# Replace the text that is inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i remove the text

`<h4>About Us</h4>` with `<a href='#aboutus'>About Us</a>` that is inside the `<div class="footer-block">`

I tried to do

`$( "div.second" ).replaceWith( "<h4><a href='#aboutus'>About Us</a></h4>" );`

But it needs some class .. But i simply have `<h4>About Us</h4>` How can i do this..

```
<div class="footer-block">
<div id="custom-menu-wizard-2"><h4>About Us</h4><div class="menu-footer_about_menu-container">
<ul id="menu-footer_about_menu" class="menu-widget  " data-cmwv="3.1.3"><li id="menu-item-1054"><a href="http://projects.bizarresoftware.in/innomations/?page_id=38&amp;tab=1">Corporate Profile</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1055" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom cmw-level-1 menu-item-1055"><a href="http://projects.bizarresoftware.in/innomations/?page_id=38&amp;tab=2">Vision</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1056" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom cmw-level-1 menu-item-1056"><a href="http://projects.bizarresoftware.in/innomations/?page_id=38&amp;tab=3">Mission</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1057" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom cmw-level-1 menu-item-1057"><a href="http://projects.bizarresoftware.in/innomations/?page_id=38&amp;tab=4">Core Team</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**Note :**

I can't simply do replaceWith the  as it will replace all the `h4` in the page.. How can i traverse inside the `footer-block` and then do the replace.

Comment: Can't you directly select h4 under **#custom-menu-wizard-2** and use **replaceWith**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ReplaceWith` function is not wrong, you have just to put the right  selector `'#custom-menu-wizard-2 h4'`.

```js
$( '#custom-menu-wizard-2 h4' ).replaceWith( "<h4><a href='#aboutus'>About Us</a></h4>" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer-block">
  <div id="custom-menu-wizard-2"><h4>About Us</h4><div class="menu-footer_about_menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-footer_about_menu" class="menu-widget  " data-cmwv="3.1.3"><li id="menu-item-1054"><a href="http://projects.bizarresoftware.in/innomations/?page_id=38&amp;tab=1">Corporate Profile</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-1055" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom cmw-level-1 menu-item-1055"><a href="http://projects.bizarresoftware.in/innomations/?page_id=38&amp;tab=2">Vision</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-1056" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom cmw-level-1 menu-item-1056"><a href="http://projects.bizarresoftware.in/innomations/?page_id=38&amp;tab=3">Mission</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-1057" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom cmw-level-1 menu-item-1057"><a href="http://projects.bizarresoftware.in/innomations/?page_id=38&amp;tab=4">Core Team</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function of html:

```
$('#custom-menu-wizard-2 h4').html(function(){
  return "<a href='#aboutus'/>" +  $(this).html() + "</a>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Replace with` here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/uprkhz8n/)

```
$( '#custom-menu-wizard-2 h4' ).replaceWith( "<h4><a href='#aboutus'>About Us</a></h4>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

`$( ".footer-block h4" ).html( "<a href='#aboutus'>About Us</a>" );`

Comment: Mine is div, so place replace your script with `#` instead or `.`

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$( "#custom-menu-wizard-2 h4:first-child").replaceWith( "<h4><a href='#aboutus'>About Us</a></h4>" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#custom-menu-wizard-2').find('h4').remove();
$('#custom-menu-wizard-2').html('<a href='#aboutus'>About Us</a>');
```

Considering there is no other element or text inside '`#custom-menu-wizard-2`'

Comment: Your second line would remove all content from $('#custom-menu-wizard-2') and just put a link in there

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrapInner() jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darxide/y1wr44oL/

```
$('.footer-block h4').wrapInner("<a href='#aboutus'></a>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( ".footer-block h4" ).replaceWith( "<a href='#aboutus'>About Us</a>" );
```

[check fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g373y6y1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("div#custom-menu-wizard-2 h4").replaceWith('<h4><a href=\'#aboutus\'>About Us</a></h4>');
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.) –